# I tried to add request scope in to provider but it will give Error: Unknown authentication strategy "jwt"

Tags: mongoose, scope, nestjs, nest

**i am using passport module and JwtStrategy module for authentication**

```
export const databaseProviders  = [

provide: 'DATABASE_CONNECTION',
scope: Scope.REQUEST,
useFactory: async (tenantService:TenantService) => {

return mongoose.connect(`mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/${tenant}`,options)

},inject: [TenantService,REQUEST]}]
```

Comment: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), Please [edit] the question, and re-format it.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue when setting up multi-tenancy with NestJS.  In your `JwtStrategy` you need to inject `ModuleRef` and set `passReqToCallback` to true.

```js
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private moduleRef: ModuleRef) {
    super({
      passReqToCallback: true
    });
  }

  public async validate(payload: any): Promise<any> {
    // Validation here
  }
}
```

You will use the `ModuleRef` to resolve any request-scoped dependencies that you need.

```js
public async validate(request: Request, payload: any) {
  const contextId = ContextIdFactory.getByRequest(request);
  // "AuthService" is a request-scoped provider
  const authService = await this.moduleRef.resolve(AuthService, contextId);
  ...
}
```

https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication#request-scoped-strategies
https://github.com/jmw5598/nestjs-angular-multitenancy

Comment: thanks for your answer but I changed the code and put in JwtStrategy class and still it's not working. there is a class called LocalStrategy in your github repo. actually what the use of that class for the authentication

Comment: @bahsw The `LocalStrategy` handles the authentication with a username and password where as the `JwtStrategy` handles the validation of the JWT tokens.  Does that answer your question?